# Eliminating null value nested array php

Tags: php, arrays

I have an array and contents nested inside the original array. The contents of the array look like-

$myArray

```
[0] => Array(
[ID] => 1
[Fruit] => Apple
[State] => Ohio
[description]
   Array(
     [0] => This is sample description
     [1] => This is sample description 2
     [2] => 
     [3] => 
     [4] => 


)
 [price]
   Array(
     [0] => 20
     [1] => 15
     [2] => 
     [3] => 
     [4] => 
)
[1] => Array(
[ID] => 1
[Fruit] => Apple
[State] => Ohio
[description]
   Array(
     [0] => This is sample description
     [1] => This is sample description 2
     [2] => 
     [3] => 
     [4] => 
)
[price]
   Array(
     [0] => 20
     [1] => 15
     [2] => 
     [3] => 
     [4] => 
)
```

I want to get rid of the `null` values in the nested array. When i use the following:

```
$newArray = array();
foreach ($firstArray as $row){
    if ($row !== null)
        $newArray[] = $row;

}
echo $newArray;
```

The new array does not get rid of the `null` values in the array.

Comment: `array_filter` is the droid you're looking for

Comment: check for `empty` value too with null comparison

Comment: Replace the array in the question with the output of `var_export($myArray)` or provide a sandbox.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do it like below:-

```
function array_filter_to_each_sub_array_recursively($input){
    foreach ($input as &$value){
        if (is_array($value)){
            $value = array_filter_to_each_sub_array_recursively($value);
        }
    }
    return array_filter($input);
}

$myArray = array_filter_to_each_sub_array_recursively($myArray);

print_r($myArray);
```

Output:-https://eval.in/833982

Comment: Nice function! Work fine!